# Primitive int value conversion?

Tags: java

```
public class Test3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i = 010;
        System.out.println(i); // prints 8          
    }

}
```

How come it prints 8? How is it getting converted? Debugging the program didn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`010` is parsed as an octal number (as any number literal starting with `0`). Its decimal value is 8. `System.out.println` prints the decimal value.

Comment: Is there any way I can convert it manually when I see a question like this as I got this question from SCJP book

Comment: @KiritiK What do you mean by "convert it manually"? Convert it to what?

Comment: octal to decimal or decimal to octal coversion

Comment: @KiritiK You can always use `Integer.toString(i, radix)` to print the number in any base you wish. For example `Integer.toString(i, 8)` will print 10.

Comment: I agree, but in exam(scjp) I can't use java program, I might have to do it in my mind or on paper so any ideas please

Comment: @KiritiK Octal is just base 8. It's similar to decimal, but instead of counting `1, 2, 3, ... 9, 10` it's `1, 2, 3, ... 6, 7, 10`. Converting the number 545 from octal to decimal: `5x8^2+4x8^1+5x8^0 = 357`.

Answer (score 3):

> Any number of digits, optionally preceded by a sign (+ or -). Decimal digits assumed by default (0-9), but a 0 prefix introduces octal digits (0-7), and > 0x hexadecimal digits (0-f).

Since you prefixed 10 with a 0 then it's read as an octal rather than decimal.

Converting octal to decimal in Java:

```
String octal = "010";
int decimal = Integer.parseInt(octal, 10);

System.out.println(decimal);
```

Output:

```
10
```

Comment: Is there any way I can convert it manually when I see a question like this as I got this question from SCJP book

Comment: @Kiritik added how to convert from `octal` to `decimal` via the `Integer#parseInt` method.

Answer (score 0):

This is octal to decimal conversion.For more info:http://www.buzzle.com/articles/octal-to-decimal-how-to-convert.html