# Initialize 0588235294117647 value in java

Tags: java

When I get a input as long datatype, the compiler does not accept the following number

```
0588235294117647
```

but if I place the zero other than first position, it is executed.

How can I declare the long number starting with zero ?

My Input

```
0588235294117647L------->Error
```

After Change

```
5088235294117647L------->No Error
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Primitive int value conversion?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29982566/primitive-int-value-conversion)

Comment: If you want a number to start with `0`, other than zero, use a `String` or something similar. Note: This will no longer make it a *number*.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is 08 not a valid integer literal in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7218760/why-is-08-not-a-valid-integer-literal-in-java)

Answer (score 7):

The leading zero tells the compiler that it is an [octal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) constant, which does not accept digits larger than 7.

This is independent of the long data type, which simply specifies the size of the integer, not the format of the constant.

Omit the leading zero and this will work.